# flags needed to compile __asm code

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

Are there any flags needed to compile code with inlined assembly instructions?

I am trying to get g++ compile the following code (cloned from an answer here on SO):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline unsigned int get_cpu_feature_flags()
{
    unsigned int features;

    __asm
    {                             // <- Line 10
        // Save registers
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        // Get the feature flags (eax=1) from edx
        mov     eax, 1
        cpuid
        mov     features, edx

        // Restore registers
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebx
        pop     eax
    }

    return features;
}

int main() {
    // Bit 26 for SSE2 support
    static const bool cpu_supports_sse2 = (get_cpu_feature_flags() & 0x04000000)!=0;
    cout << (cpu_supports_sse2? "Supports SSE" : "Does NOT support SSE");
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
$ g++ t2.cpp 
t2.cpp: In function ‘unsigned int get_cpu_feature_flags()’:
t2.cpp:10:5: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
t2.cpp:12:9: error: ‘push’ was not declared in this scope
t2.cpp:12:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘eax’
$
```

Comment: That looks like something VC++ would accept (on Windows). You can find various other implementations in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID).

Comment: `__asm` is a VC++ extension. The C++ standard assembly statement looks like `asm("code here");` Gcc uses the standard form, and extends it with a few more string literals to declare inputs, outputs, and other constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have hinted but not said explicitly, this is incorrect syntax for gcc (which uses a string-based asm("...") language instead of true inline assembly code) and for gas (which uses AT&T syntax instead of Intel syntax).

A google for "gcc inline assembly" pulls up this tutorial, which looks good:

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

And you can find the relevant section of the gcc documentation here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
__asm(
   //...
)
```

not

```
__asm{
   //...
}
```

Also, note that the standard version is `asm`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it says `t2.cpp:12:9: error: expected string-literal before ‘push’`. Is there something else I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It *is* `__asm { }` in [Microsoft Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Lazer: Don't be a cargo cult programmer. *Understand* what you're writing and why you're writing it. Start from the beginning: you want to include assembly instructions in your code in GCC. Start searching and learn to do it properly, not just by guessing over and over.

Comment: @GManNickG: appreciate it. Could you please point me to tutorials / articles regarding how to get started? I did not find any good explanation on the internet so far. Thanks.

Comment: @BoPersson The standard clearly states `()`. Is that a MS language extension?

Comment: @Lazer: Andy Ross below posted a good answer that can get you started. Note that there are two things to keep in mind: avoid inline assembly if you can. As you can see, it's highly platform-specific, so you introduce a lot of work when compiling across compilers and platforms. That said, in your case you probably cannot get around that, but take a minute to see if such functionality exists as an OS API call instead. Then at least the hard work is done. Second, you're going to have to duplicate this assembly, and select which syntax to use based on a preprocessor branch.

Answer (score 0):

For `gcc` inline assembly, the syntax is `asm("<instructions>" : "<output constraints>" : "<input constraints>")`. Note the use of parentheses instead of braces, and that instructions (and the optional constraint clauses) are placed in string literals.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this syntax to be specific to ARM processors, and MS asm. See

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABFDCGD.html

If it is another processor or compiler (like Keil) consult their support pages.